# Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION in Android Pie and Q

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, foreground-service, android-mediaprojection

any body knows why this error occur, Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION on   getMediaProjection() even i call  getMediaProjection() method after calling startforeground() method..!

Stack Trace is :

```
  Process: com.al1.screenrecorder, PID: 24641
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.al1.screenrecorder.service.DisplayRecorderService@9ef2101 with Intent { cmp=com.al1.screenrecorder/.service.DisplayRecorderService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4661)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:292)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
    at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
    at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:75)
    at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
    at com.al1.screenrecorder.service.DisplayRecorderService.createMediaProjection(DisplayRecorderService.java:118)
    at com.al1.screenrecorder.service.DisplayRecorderService.onStartCommand(DisplayRecorderService.java:107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4641)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:292) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8147) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101) 
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:498)
    at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1028)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1001)
```

**strong text**
       private void startForeground() {

```
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    activityIntent.setAction("stop");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        String channelId = "001";
        String channelName = "myChannel";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (manager != null) {
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            Notification notification = new Notification.
                    Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.ClickToCancel))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .build();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startForeground(0, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
            } else {
                startForeground(0, notification);
            }
        }
    } else {
        startForeground(0, new Notification());
    }

}
```

and onStartCommand is :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand() is called");

    startForeground();

    mResultCode = intent.getIntExtra("code", -1);
    mResultData = intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
    mScreenWidth = intent.getIntExtra("width", 720);
    mScreenHeight = intent.getIntExtra("height", 1280);
    mScreenDensity = intent.getIntExtra("density", 1);
    isVideoSd = intent.getBooleanExtra("quality", true);
    isAudio = intent.getBooleanExtra("audio", true);


    mMediaProjection = createMediaProjection();
    mMediaRecorder = createMediaRecorder();
    mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
    mMediaRecorder.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

and exception is in this method on getMediaProjection:

```
 private MediaProjection createMediaProjection() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Create MediaProjection");
    return ((MediaProjectionManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE))).
            getMediaProjection(mResultCode, mResultData);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"` to the `<service>` element in the manifest for your service.

Comment: please review again i edited my post and added the stack trace

Comment: @MirzaAli: AFAIK, `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION` is solved by having `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"` on the `<service>` element for the service in the manifest.

Comment: <service
            android:name=".service.DisplayRecorderService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />

Comment: Hey @MirzaAli, did you get the solution?

Comment: <service
            android:name=".Circle_notification.FloatingViewService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />    i have no solution my app is not working

Comment: Also not working in my app.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping `getMediaProjection(mResultCode, mResultData)` inside a `Handler().postDelayed()` solved the problem for me.

```
override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        val binder = service as MediaProjectionService.LocalBinder
        mediaProjectionService = binder.getService()

        // delay needed because getMediaProjection() throws an error if it's called too soon
        Handler().postDelayed({
            mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(activityResultCode, activityData)
            startStreaming()
            serviceBound = true
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: wow, It worked for me. I understand why I had the issue

Answer (score 3):

You have to start a foreground service bit before you create media projection.

If you have already a service, there will be a delay to start the service most times even if you start service before you initialize media projection. Start projection after a slight delay after you start the service. I think this will do the trick.

code sample:

```
startService(new Intent(AppController.getInstance(),
            ScreenCaptureService.class));

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

           if (isServiceActive(context, ScreenCaptureService.class)){
               mMediaProjection =
                       projectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
               processAndSaveScreenshotFromDevice(context);
           }
        }
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with OP's code was that he used

```
startForeground(0, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
```

Docs explicitly say:

> *Params: id – The identifier for this notification as per NotificationManager.notify(int, Notification); **must not be 0**.*

Comment: The most correct answer is all available here. Thank you bro You saved my day

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have granted the required **FOREGROUND_SERVICE** permissions. If your `targetSdkVersion = 28` using foreground services must request the **FOREGROUND_SERVICE** permission.
So add **FOREGROUND_SERVICE** permission to your manifest file without which it throws **SecurityException**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

You can read more about this migration notes: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration#tya
[image: can read in this screenshot]

Hope this will help you.....

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343645/5182769. The key is you must create notification channel in onStartCommand firstly.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the foreground permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`, you need to create a service class.So in a new Java file have this:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ClassWithError.class);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, AnotherClassWithError.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0);

        Notification notification1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ScreenRecorder")
                .setContentTitle("yNote studios")
                .setContentText("Filming...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent1).build();

        Notification notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ScreenRecorder")
                .setContentTitle("yNote studios")
                .setContentText("Filming...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent1).build();

        startForeground(1, notification1);
        startForeground(2, notification2);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ScreenRecorder", "Foreground notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Then back in the manifest, add the service segment with the name section as the above service class. It should be within the application segment.

```
<service
            android:name=".Services.BackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />
```

After setting it up like that, you can access this background service whenever you need it (in the `onCreate` method) as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            startService(intent);
        }
```

But be sure to manage it. It may be the cause of several exceptions in other functions within your project. Things like media recorders will crush when invoked while this service is running. For this, use the `onDestroy` method to close the service.

Comment: I tried above solution still getting Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION. When I call capturer.StartCapture(). Also super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId) runs in infinite loop. How can we get out of service?

Comment: You should use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` instead