# How to start Media projections from foreground service

Tags: android, service, android-mediaprojection

Since I have changed SDK to 29 to be acceptable by Google Play Store I'm getting this crash when the user select screen recording

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
```

so how can I build foreground service to start media projection

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/pkrieter/android-background-screen-recorder) you can find a demo for foreground service. thay are also use

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
```

Comment: check out this links:-1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674637/error-getmediaprojection-when-targetsdkversion-29   
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591594/android-10-androidforegroundservicetype-mediaprojection-not-working-with-ser