# My app: Android 10 screen recorder doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, screen-recording

Since Android 10 I'm unable to save the video output from my so called splashscreen activity.
Basically you can define the text, speed, size and color.

When the video checkbox isn't active everything work fine. Simply display the text rows on the screen is not a problem with Android 10. As soon as video is activated and permission is granted, it will crash by pushing the accept button from the screen recorder dialog.

minSDK: 16
maxSDK: 30

I heard from foreground service but I don't know how to implement this. Can somebody help me and show me the correct position and what I have to change please?

My errors at the moment:

```
onActivityResult:387, Splashscreen (stutz.com.flash_text)
dispatchActivityResult:8110, Activity (android.app)
deliverResults:4838, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleSendResult:4886, ActivityThread (android.app)
execute:51, ActivityResultItem (android.app.servertransaction)
executeCallbacks:135, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
execute:95, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
handleMessage:2016, ActivityThread$H (android.app)
dispatchMessage:107, Handler (android.os)
loop:214, Looper (android.os)
main:7356, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:492, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:930, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

My relevant code as follow:

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen"
    android:theme="@style/NoTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
        <service
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

Permission.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class Function {

    public static  boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity call after defining values:

```
    private void openSplash() {
        Intent splash = new Intent(this, Splashscreen.class);
        splash.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(splash);
    }
```

splashscreen.java:

values from mainactivity launch in splashscreen.java:

```
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.bgcolor;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.textcontent1;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.textcontent2;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.textcontent3;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.speed;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.color;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.loop;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.video;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.quality;
import static stutz.com.flash_text.MainActivity.textsizefloat;

public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Splashscreen";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY = 1;
    private int mScreenDensity;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private static int DISPLAY_WIDTH;
    private static int DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    public static boolean sharefilecheck;
    public static Uri shareuri;
    
    
        // Permission Array

    private final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    // Rotation Array

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        // Set fullscreen and screen always on

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgcolor));
        
        
                if (video && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && Function.hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS) && !novalues) {

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            DISPLAY_WIDTH = size.x;
            DISPLAY_HEIGHT = size.y;

            // Override values otherwise video could crash

            loop = false;

            if (speed < 500) {
                speed = 500;
            }

            // Start video recording

            onToggleScreenShare();

        }
        
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void onToggleScreenShare() {

        if (!isRecording) {
            initRecorder();
            shareScreen();
        } else {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void shareScreen() {
        if (mMediaProjection == null) {
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
    
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void stopScreenSharing() {
        if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay.release();
        destroyMediaProjection();
        isRecording = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Video saved");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved on int/ext Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void destroyMediaProjection() {
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaProjection Stopped");
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isRecording) {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Recording");
            stopScreenSharing();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finish();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        destroyMediaProjection();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Splashscreen", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    // Manifest Permission Check - Function Call

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY: {
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    isRecording = false;
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please enable Storage permissions.",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intentP = new Intent();
                                    intentP.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    intentP.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                                    intentP.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                                    intentP.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intentP.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
                                    intentP.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                    intentP.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                    startActivity(intentP);

                                }

                            }

                    ).show();


                }

            }

        }


    }

// Display Permission Window

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please accept to make a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isRecording = false;
            finish();
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Canceled");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled. You have to accept to make a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isRecording = false;
            finish();
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
           mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
           mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
           mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
           mMediaRecorder.start();
           isRecording = true;
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            if (isRecording) {
                isRecording = false;
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
            }
            mMediaProjection = null;
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); //THREE_GPP
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String sDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "_"
                    + c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                    + "_" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    + "-" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                    + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                    + "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            String savestring = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/Flash_Text_" + sDate + ".mp4";
            shareuri = Uri.parse(savestring);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(savestring);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(quality);
            sharefilecheck = true;
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:
Extended Crashlog:

```
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime: Process: stutz.com.flash_text, PID: 22718
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, da
ta=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {stutz.com.flash_text/stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections requir
e a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:
135)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type Service
Info.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.ja
va:104)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen.onActivityResult(Splashscreen.java:387)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 11 more
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(Medi
aProjectionManagerService.java:476)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
11-06 20:10:46.908 22718 22718 E AndroidRuntime:
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime: Process: stutz.com.flash_text, PID: 23616
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, da
ta=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {stutz.com.flash_text/stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections requir
e a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:
135)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type Service
Info.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.ja
va:104)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen.onActivityResult(Splashscreen.java:387)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 11 more
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(Medi
aProjectionManagerService.java:476)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
11-06 20:18:34.779 23616 23616 E AndroidRuntime:
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime: Process: stutz.com.flash_text, PID: 24212
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, da
ta=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {stutz.com.flash_text/stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections requir
e a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:
135)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type Service
Info.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.ja
va:104)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen.onActivityResult(Splashscreen.java:387)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 11 more
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(Medi
aProjectionManagerService.java:476)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
11-06 20:19:31.578 24212 24212 E AndroidRuntime:
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime: Process: stutz.com.flash_text, PID: 6534
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, da
ta=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {stutz.com.flash_text/stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections requir
e a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:
135)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type Service
Info.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.ja
va:104)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at stutz.com.flash_text.Splashscreen.onActivityResult(Splashscreen.java:387)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
11-09 17:33:04.746  6534  6534 E AndroidRuntime:        at
```

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: I have added the extended crashlog but I was limited to total 30k chars.

Comment: I'd search more about `java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION`. Probably it's a new thing in Android 10. It's not a familiar topic to me. For example this is related and has an answer from a reputable Android expert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276730/media-projections-require-a-foreground-service-of-type-serviceinfo-foreground-se

Comment: In Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo#FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION it does say _"Added in API level 29"_