# Error getMediaProjection when targetSdkVersion 29

Tags: android, api

I am building a screen recording application. But it only works on targetSdkVersion 28, when passing targetSdkVersion 29 requested by google, the error

Code

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Screen Cast Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();

        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
```

Error was thrown

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster, PID: 21862
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster/com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
        at com.megamestudio.screen_record_and_booster.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:426)
```

Please help me, thanks

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276730/media-projections-require-a-foreground-service-of-type-serviceinfo-foreground-se)

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I cannot downgrade to api 28 because google requires api 29

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Koradiya I cannot downgrade to api 28 because google requires api 29

Comment: check last answer at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277020/7783718

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Thank you very much, let me ask more for my code what "android:name=??" do I need to fill in for it to work

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I mean this code <service android:name=".service.DisplayRecorderService" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> this code I have declared already

Comment: @BửuHoàng: Did you find answer for this question. I have tried all of the above still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution after some time of research.
First of all, follow the other answers.

1. manifest permission
2. start service on the foreground

#### this is the answer that I had

3. On the service, onStartCommand(), I implemented this method for the android Q. (less than Q, it works without this codes): startForeground(id, notification, serviceType)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Notification notification = ScreenRecorderHelper.GetMediaProjectionNotification(AppShared.gContext);
            startForeground(startId,
                    notification,
                    ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
        }



        handleCommand(intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

I hope this helps many others like me...

Comment: yes , that `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION` is required for `MediaProjection` . I just caught  this dedicated to Media Projection  thread with `Handler` and then afterward used it via `handler.postDelayed( Runnable, DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS)` and finally it works !

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"` to the  element in the manifest for your service and this issue will be gone.