# How to implement screen sharing in flutter? I seen lot of solution implement screen sharing in android, but not for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, matrix, screensharing

I'm using the [matrix package](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix) which is more useful for real-time communication, I've achieved audio calls, video calls, and sending real-time messages. Now that I tried to implement the screen while calling, some default methods were there to implement the screen sharing, but my app crashed while starting the screen sharing.

I've tried the matrix methods:

```
  Future<void> handleScreenSharing() async {
    screenShared.toggle();
    await _groupCall?.setScreensharingEnabled(
      screenShared.value,
      groupCall.localDesktopCapturerSourceId,
    );
  }
```

But facing this issue:

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you add the foreground service type? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276730/media-projections-require-a-foreground-service-of-type-serviceinfo-foreground-se

Comment: Yeah! I've added that, but not worked for me